# regex find and replace characters inside html comment

Tags: regex, replace

Please help in below matter:
I would like to find character (in my case: --) and replace with other (in my case: zz, or **) but only inside html comments (`<!--  -->`).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regex flavor supports the `\G` anchor, it is done like this

Global find with `(<!--(?=[\S\s]*?-->)|(?!^)\G)((?:(?!--)[\S\s])*?)(--)(?!>)`

replace with `$1$2zz` or `$1$2**`

---

If the \G anchor is not supported it can be done with a
callback.

Match the comment `<!--([\S\s]*?)-->` in a replace call,
then in callback  replace any `--` in group 1 with `zz` or `**`, return the new  comment (possibly unchanged) to the original replacement.
Construct it like `return "<!--" + newcontent + "-->";`